# $Df(x,y) = \nabla4(x^3-y,y^3-x)$

Tags: derivatives

In a textbook I found this:
$$ f(x,y) = x^4+y^4-4xy $$
$$ Df(x,y) = \nabla4(x^3-y,y^3-x)$$

Shouldnt it be:
$$ Df(x,y) = 4(x^3-y,y^3-x)$$

Am I missing something here?

Comment: That's probably a typo.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was already scratching my head ;)

Comment: Maybe I should mention that $D \ F=\nabla \ F$

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. It should be $Df(x,y) = \nabla f(x,y) = 4(x^3-y,y^3-x)$.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Im studying the whole day and thought I got everything. And then I saw this and thought Im gonna go crazy ;)